# On-delay circuit not working

Tags: capacitor, bjt, 555, zener, delay

I'm trying to make On-delay circuit with  passive components, I use 3 identical AAA alkaline batteries (4.5 v) and use PNP 2N2907  Bjt with 600mA Collector Current to heat(glow) up a small resistor wire

I use a 1000 uF capacitor and 20k Pot resistor for adjustable RC delay, Also I use 6.1v Zener diode
however, when I press push button in my circuit the heating element does not even warm-up

following is my schematic

my question is:

Is Bjt not powerful enough to deliver current and heat up the element,

or is my schematic wrong and I should select another component?

if the current is not enough how can I add a wire coil inductor to charge on delay and push more current to the heating element?

[image]

updated schematic

[image]

updated schematic  base on new comments

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us how much current the heating element draws when cold and when hot, and how much delay you want?

Comment: @GodJihyo I think my heating element need around 1 Amp and want to delay not more than 10 seconds

Comment: If you need 1A a 600mA transistor isn't going to handle it. And if it takes 1A when it's heated it will take a lot more when cold.

Comment: @GodJihyo can parallel two Bjt?

Comment: It's possible but you still have other problems. You need to know the characteristics of the load and the power source. What is the current draw profile of the load? Will the batteries supply the current you need for the time that you need it?  And we haven't even gotten to the matter of whether the time delay will work or not.

Comment: The zener diode will never conduct. Its breakdown voltage is greater than the voltage from the batteries. Neither transistor will ever conduct. Also, if  the batteries are connected as shown, they're backwards. Why do you want a 10 second delay? If you get the circuit working it won't do anything more than waiting 10 seconds before pushing the switch.

Comment: If you want to start a time delay after pressing the button, you might want a latching circuit, best accomplished with a 555 timer. But it looks like you want to keep the output off until the button has been held for at least 10 seconds. And then will stay on as long as the button is held on.

Comment: why don't you simply press the button 10 seconds later?

Comment: Transistors and BJTs are not passive components....

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to turn on a PNP transistor with a positive voltage from base to collector, to turn on a PNP you need a negative voltage from base to emitter.

Another problem is that you are using a 6.1 V Zener but your batteries only supply 4.5 V, so the Zener will never see enough voltage to conduct. You would either need higher voltage from the batteries or a different circuit altogether.

You could try an NPN transistor and swap the emitter and collector around, but you need one that will handle the cold current of the wire and enough base current to saturate the transistor which may require using another transistor as a driver.

Other options are a MOSFET or a relay, although a relay would add extra drain on the batteries.

You need to take the initial inrush current into account. A heating wire will have a low resistance when cold and then the resistance will increase as it heats up. This will cause a large current draw on startup than when in operation. You can deal with the inrush several ways, either use a device that can handle the maximum inrush current, or limit the inrush current.

Comment: the reason I use PNP is, that I couldn't find and high current NPN in the market, but I was suspicious about the Zener diode my capacitor not break it to drive the transistor

Comment: I update the schematic

Comment: @mehrdad You can't find a high current NPN, but you can find high current PNP? That sounds really strange to me, because NPN transistors are generally better in most respects than PNP equivalents, so they're much more common, especially for power transistors.

Comment: @Hearth price tag is the most factor of this project, if I could use the parallel PNP, still is much lower than the high current NPN or MOSFET or even N555 timer

Answer (score 0):

That time delay circuit needs a complete redesign, so here is my idea for something that should work. It uses an NPN/PNP pair as an SCR, so it will latch on and remain on as long as power is applied.

[image: Time delay simulation LTSpice]

Comment: price tag is the most factor of this project, although your circuit works it needs more components,  then  the price is more than N555 timer (robust solution) , can you check the new circuit update

Comment: Simulate it or build it and find out. Or use an actual SCR.